# Loop stacked in an function. Works when not in the function

Tags: r

So originally I was going to post this as an issue on the libraries github but when making a minimum reproducible example I realized the issue has to do with functions and loop interactions more This is only a small section as the end result is creation of tables from a survey so can't just remove the loop from the function. Here is the minimal code to test. Attached are results. Looking for some help on how to work around this where I can call this from inside the function but get the proper result

Set up

```r
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(magrittr)

gt_table <- tibble( q1 = c(0,1,2,3,4), n_CAT1 = c(23,56,61,76,41), n_CAT2 = c(18,31,31,26,12), n_CAT3 = c(18,24,25,38,20), percent_CAT1 = c(0.046,0.112,0.112,0.152,0.082), percent_CAT2 = c(0.036,0.062,0.062,0.052,0.025), percent_CAT3 = c(0.036,0.048,0.050,0.076,0.040))

dfl <- c("CAT1","CAT2","CAT3")
```

Version 1. This works when not in a function, have to have this sadly

```
gti <- gt_table %>% gt()
for(i in 1:length(dfl)){
   nf <- paste("percent_",dfl[i],sep="")
   pf <- paste("n_", dfl[i],sep="")
   lf <- dfl[i]
   gti %<>% tab_spanner(label=lf, columns=vars(nf,pf))
}

gti
```

[Output v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgG5p.jpg)

Version 2. This doesn't work

```
test_fun <- function(gt_table, dfl){
   gti <- gt_table %>% gt()
   for(i in 1:length(dfl)){
      nf <- paste("percent_",dfl[i],sep="")
      pf <- paste("n_", dfl[i],sep="")
      lf <- dfl[i]
     gti %<>% tab_spanner(label=lf, columns=vars(nf,pf))
   }
   return(gti)
}

test <- test_fun(gt_table,dfl) %T>% print
```

[Output v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUAGa.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, `columns = vars(nf, pf)` is getting `nf` and `pf` from the global environment rather than the ones defined inside the function.

I'm not sure why this is happening but the solution is to replace `vars` with `all_of` which is the preferred way of selecting using a character vector.

```
test_fun <- function(gt_table, dfl){
  gti <- gt_table %>% gt()
  for(i in 1:length(dfl)){
    nf <- paste("percent_", dfl[i], sep="")
    pf <- paste("n_", dfl[i], sep="")
    lf <- dfl[i]
    gti %<>% tab_spanner(label = lf, columns = all_of(c(nf, pf)))
  }
  gti
}

test_fun(gt_table, dfl)
```

[image: result]